# Selenium Loop append multiple tables together

Tags: pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, append, concatenation

I am a new python user here. I have been writing a code that uses selenium and beautiful soup to go to a website and get the html table and turn it into a data frame.

I am using selenium to loop though a number of different pages and beautiful soup to collect the table from there.

The issue that I am running into is I can't get all those tables to append to each other. If i print off the dataframe it only prints the last table that was scraped. How do I tell beautifulsoup to append one dataframe to the bottom of the other?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's been a couple days at this one little part.

```
states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia",
"Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", 
"Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire",
"New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
"Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", 
"Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]

period = "2020"

num_states = len(states)

state_list = []

for state in states:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
    drp = Select(state_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
    year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
    drp = Select(year_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
    link.click()
    url = driver.current_url
    page = requests.get(url)
    #dfs  = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
    # Get the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.findAll('table')[2]
    headers = []

    for i in table.find_all('th'):
        title = i.text.strip()
        headers.append(title)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row_data
    df = pd.DataFrame.rename(columns={'Total Acres':'Total_acres'})
    for i in range(s,num_states):
        state_list.append([County[i].text, Payment[i].text, Total_acres[i].text])

print(df)
```

******************** EDIT ***********************
period = "2020"

num_states = len(states)

state_list = []

df = pd.DataFrame()

for state in states:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
drp = Select(state_s)
drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
drp = Select(year_s)
drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
link.click()
url = driver.current_url
page = requests.get(url)
#dfs  = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
# Get the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.findAll('table')[2]
headers = []

```
for i in table.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)


for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = row_data


dfs = pd.concat([df for state in states])
```

print(df)

Results in:
ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined columns

Comment: Are all the tables of the same format, eg. same columns ?  If not, probably not a good idea to append them together into one dataframe.  If yes, do you need to setup headers for every table inside the loop ?

Comment: Hi SeaBean - yes, all the tables are the exact same format

Comment: Ok, let me explain in more details below.

Comment: See my explanation below, which should let you get information from all tables.  You still need to fine-tune the logics of overwriting the columns info. in each iteration of the outermost loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accessing table through pandas!  pls refer the comment against lines which have been added.

```
states = ["Alabama", "Alaska"]

period = "2020"

num_states = len(states)

state_list = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
result=[] # change 1 , list to store the {state:df}
for state in states:
    
    driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
    drp = Select(state_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
    year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
    drp = Select(year_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
    link.click()
    url = driver.current_url
    page = requests.get(url)
    temp_res={}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    df_list=pd.read_html(soup.prettify(),thousands=',,') # access the table through pandas
    try:
        df_list[2].drop('PAYMENT.1', axis=1, inplace=True) # some states giving this column , so deleted
    except:
        print(f"state: {state} does have payment 1")
    try:
        df_list[2].drop('PAYMENT.2', axis=1, inplace=True)  # some states giving this column , so deleted
    except:
        print(f"state: {state} does have payment 2")
    temp_res[state]=df_list[2] # the table at occurance 2
    result.append(temp_res)
```

Output looks like:

```
for each_run in result :
    for each_state in each_run:
        print(each_run[each_state].head(1))
 COUNTY PAYMENT TOTAL ACRES
0  AUTAUGA COUNTY  $4,971       1,758
                   COUNTY   PAYMENT TOTAL ACRES
0  ALEUTIANS EAST BOROUGH  $668,816   2,663,160
```