# Get the content of multiple classes when scraping a website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The problem that I am facing is simple. If I am trying to get some data from a website, there are **two classes** with the **same name**. But they both contain a table with different Information. The code that I have only outputs me the content of the very first class. It looks like this:

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find("tr", {"class": "table3"})
print(results.prettify())
```

How can I get the code to put out either the content of both tables or only the content of the second one?
Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Locate the XPaths of both elements and you can access them individually: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup/

Comment: I have tried it but the list it creates is empty. I don't know why it seems to be the case with any element on the website.

Comment: you can also try pandas read_html as a quick way `df_list=pd.read_html(url)` , if your page has two tables, the result will have two entries in df_list, and you can access particular table as df_list[0] or df_list[1]. something like my response on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219371/selenium-loop-append-multiple-tables-together

Comment: What is the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find_all()` and `[1]` to get second result. Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """
<tr class="table3"> I don't want this </tr>
<tr class="table3"> I want this! </tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("tr", class_="table3")
print(results[1])  # <-- get only second one
```

Prints:

```html
<tr class="table3"> I want this! </tr>
```